# Piping internally in Perl

Tags: pipe, perl

I have a script that consists roughly of two parts:

1. A preprocessing of the incoming input (where I may omit, merge, add lines to the output);
2. A second stage where I do the actual processing.

Would it be possible to somehow pipe that first part of the program to the second part of the (Perl) program? I would prefer doing that to having to do both things at the same time.

Just to give a rough idea of what I currently have for step 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $block = '';
while (my $line = <>) {
  if ($line =~ /^\[.*\] \[.*\] \[.*\] .*: /) {
    if ($block ne '') {
        print $block;
    }
    $block = $line;
  } else {
    $block = $block . $line;
  }
}

if ($block ne '') {
  print $block;
}
```

(Step 2 should only deal with blocks, not with individual lines)

EDIT:

Example of input:

```
[global-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2973] [DEBUG] [2017-04-18 15:41:07,077] c.e.d.s.o.AbcService: Dropping update:  (ID: 1644856891, Version: 7
name: "BBB CCC"
disabled_position: true
, status id 128385 )
[global-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2973] [DEBUG] [2017-04-18 15:41:07,077] c.e.d.s.o.AbcService: something else
[global-akka.actor.default] [ERROR] [2017-04-18 15:41:07,077] c.e.d.s.o.DefService: yet something else
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not put your processed blocks into an array and then process that array later in the execution?

Comment: Yes, it's the alternative I was thinking about.

Comment: There is no need for _piping_ at all. But you probably didn't actually mean two programs anyway. How much data do you expect? Can you keep all of it in memory? You're currently not showing how your input works. Is one block the complete input for one invocation of this program? Do you have to run it like that, or is writing it in one go in a Perl program an option?

Comment: (You don't need `-w` in the shebang if you have `use warnings`)

Comment: @simbabque: I can't keep the whole file in memory, it's potentially GBs in size, although I can certainly keep all the lines for a given block in memory (the average should be just 1-5 lines, once in a while 30-50 max).

Comment: I think I would just do that it at the same time. Instead of the upper `print $block` I'd do `process($block)` and have function do the processing. Pretty straight-forward. Don't keep around the stuff. Just deal with it.

Comment: I think this is easier than it sounds, but ... some sample input would help, as would some desired output. I think you'll _probably_ find setting `$/` to something appropriate for the record format you're using, will let you do what you want.

Comment: @Sobrique I don't think the $/ will work, from what I saw. Because I would need a regexp to know when a new line is really starting. Or is it possible to use $/ with regexps?

Comment: No, you cannot regex match it. However you probably can set it to `\n[` in your example.